# Remove [coprocessor] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [coprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coprocessor) tag has only seven questions, not even being related as they mean different things with the term “coprocessor” and there is no tag wiki describing an intended use. So we can’t even say that some of these questions are using the tag wrongly…

Comment: just seven questions, wouldn't it have been easier to just remove the tags? "Use [burninate-request] in case of uncertainty when requesting discussion, or when the popularity of the tag makes manual retagging followed by automatic culling of 0-question tags prohibitively difficult."

Comment: @eis: I didn’t find a documentation saying that I should do that. The documentation of `[burninate-request]` says I should leave the tag alone if it already has zero questions, it does not say that I should actively work in that direction. I really searched for procedures regarding removing tags, I did not find something like “go ahead and remove the tag from all questions”…

Comment: My quote was from the wiki summary of that tag.

Comment: @eis: the quoted part says when to use it but doesn’t say what to do otherwise. The idea of me removing these tags was your comment’s first sentence which doesn’t seem to be a quote. As said, I looked for a resource suggesting me that (or another action to take). If you have one, feel free to post the link, I’m happy to learn which page I missed.

Comment: I interpret the quote as suggesting manual retagging the way to proceed when there are only few applicable posts. But I agree other documentation doesn't really say so.

Comment: How can we make this title a pun?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has been burninated.

[image]

Comment: Globex rules...!