# what constitutes a good tag [or nipping bad tags in the bud]

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

Ok, so today while looking at my [SO moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) this new created tag -> [paranoia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paranoia) catches my eye! So one guy ended up creating it for this one specific question.

I thought it was a mistake but looking it up I find it's a ruby framework :https://github.com/radar/paranoia

But more, I find, it's a rewrite for an [older framework](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) which also has an *odd* tag name IMO -> [acts-as-paranoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acts-as-paranoid) with 8 questions.

Now, for the **short term my question** is, should I rename `paranoia` ? I definitely think it should be `paranoia-framework` or something?

But in the broader scheme of things, words like *"paranoia"* make for odd tags which a year or so later we'll be [hurrying to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300510/remove-coprocessor-tag?cb=1) [burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new/burninate-request?show=all&sort=recentlyactive).

So my **broader question** is how do we handle this sort of thing, what convention or standard should be used for a new tag ? (Eg: Does the framework - *in this case* have to be popular ? Is a very specific name better, like `paranoia-framework` vs `paranoia`)

Comment: No need to tinker with it when it is unambiguous.  It isn't a "framework" either, it is a Ruby gem.  Postfixing -gem is not necessary, gem tags don't use it.  Just as it wasn't necessary on [acts-as-paranoid].

Comment: MSE dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155646/are-there-any-general-rules-for-when-a-new-tag-should-be-created

Comment: Dang Ruby hipsters hijacking all the names. Back in the olden days paranoia was a CD ripper.

Comment: If "paranioa" was ambiguous I think it would make more sense to disambiguate it with "ruby-paranioa". It's more likely be unique and remain  unique in the scope of the programming language, than the scope of all frameworks (or plugins, as it appears to call itself) across all languages.

Comment: `[ruby-paranoia]` would make the most sense.

Comment: @TinyGiant I like your suggestion. There seem to be such a mixed opinion about this. (The votes on my Q and the A) Not sure what to do now lol! . Nathan I don't see that post as a dupe. While that one asks about general creation of tags and whether the community (as he's noticed, shuns it) my post is about a very specific case.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created a [tag:ruby-paranoia], if anyone supports that and would help peer review the tag wiki.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's fine.  It's a specific, narrow, pointed library which [people are indeed using](https://rubygems.org/gems/paranoia/versions/2.1.3) just the same as `acts_as_paranoid`.  For this case, despite the fact that these two libraries act very similarly, I see no reason to introduce any changes to these tags.

The main reason here:  Paranoia makes it a point to explicitly support Rails 3 and 4, whereas `acts_as_paranoid` probably didn't in the past.  If there are any rough spots with someone using `paranoia` in Rails 5, for instance, it'd be good to be explicit about which library was actually being used, in spite of their similarities.